# Label sometimes sticks into other labels. Winforms basic game with movement and colision

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I have created a game that i find mostly finished. The only problem is that sometimes when you move towards a wall which also is a label, you get stuck.
Believe me when i say this that this is going to be superhard for me to explain, and i believe even harder for you to solve.

Okay so i will give some basic information first i think that will help.

It is a maze game with a player moving with arrowkeys using bools to determine which direction to go. 
Walls are also labels and gets colision from this

```
    private List<Label> GetLabels(Control control)
    {

        foreach (var childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            if (childControl is Label && ((Label)childControl).Name != "player")
            {
                Labels.Add((Label)childControl);
            }
            else
            {
                GetLabels((Control)childControl);
            }
        }
        return Labels;
    }
```

Movement occurs when timer1 is enabled and either right left up or down is true by keyDown action.
Ive made it so that when you colide with a wall you get ported 1 pixel in the opposite direction you where facing when you hit the wall with this code

```
            if (Right)
            {
                Right = false;
                player.Left -= 2 + i;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (Left)
            {
                Left = false;
                player.Left += 2 + i;
                timer1.Enabled = false;
            }
```

To add is that i is the velocity of player.

So people. What might be the problem? If you need any more code or data please ask i will be monitoring this with my full attention.

EDIT:

This is how i check for colision

```
    foreach (var label in Labels.Where( label => player.Bounds.IntersectsWith(label.Bounds)))

    private List<Label> GetLabels(Control control)
    {

        foreach (var childControl in control.Controls)
        {
            if (childControl is Label && ((Label)childControl).Name != "player")
            {
                Labels.Add((Label)childControl);
            }
            else
            {
                GetLabels((Control)childControl);
            }
        }
        return Labels;
    }
```

Comment: For future projects, I'd recommend at least using GDI+ if you're using WinForms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yysstebh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @zmarks22 Thank you for the addition, I might ask my teacher if he would explain some basic GDI for us.

Answer (score 0):

When checking for collision I would recommend checking with velocity included. For example, if I'm checking for a collection on the left side of the player...

```
//Velocity included
if(player.Left - i <= wall.Right)

//Velocity unaccounted for
if(player.Left <= wall.Right
```

Comment: Isnt that what i have done when i added the 'i' to the bumb back upon colision?

Comment: Possibly, although I haven't seen your actual collision check. Just speaking from experience though, moving the object into the wall and then moving it back out is asking for collision anomalies like it getting stuck in the wall.

Comment: If you're only using `IntersectsWith`, how are you setting your `Right` and `Left` booleans?

Comment: Yupp. Got any clue on how to fix? i get what you said on how porting back after colision asks for truble but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: I'd create a custom bounds collision function rather than the built-in IntersectsWith function, incorporate velocity into that function, and prevent movement if collision is true.